# EJB Exception from readValue on ValueHandler in CDRInputStream. JNDI

Tags: java, ejb, jndi

I have server side classes

```
@Remote
public interface IQuoteSetEJB extends Serializable {

    QuoteSetInterface getConnection() throws Exception;
}
```

And I have class implementation:

```
@Stateful(name = "IQuoteSetEJB", mappedName = "ejb/QuoteSet_EsbWs")
public class QuoteSet_EsbWs implements IQuoteSetEJB, Serializable {

    @Override
    public QuoteSetInterface getConnection() throws Exception {

        QuoteSetInterface quoteSetInterface = null;
        QuoteSetInterface_Service quoteSetInterface_service = null;

        if(null == quoteSetInterface_service) {
            quoteSetInterface_service = new QuoteSetInterface_Service(new URL("http://localhost:7804/esbservice/quoteset?wsdl"));
        }

        if(null == quoteSetInterface) {
            quoteSetInterface = quoteSetInterface_service.getQuoteSetInterfaceSOAP();
        }
        return quoteSetInterface;
    }

}
```

Implemented on glassfish 4.1 as jar file.

And I have client remote like:

```
@EJB
private static IQuoteSetEJB iEsbWsJndi;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ACTPropertyReader actPropertyReader = new ACTPropertyReader();
    actPropertyReader.getPropertyConfig();


    try {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
        props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "10.218.49.20");
        //props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "localhost");

        // glassfish default port value will be 3700,
        props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");

        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(props);

        iEsbWsJndi = (IQuoteSetEJB) ctx.lookup("ejb/QuoteSet_EsbWs");
        System.out.println(iEsbWsJndi.getConnection());


    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

WhenI invoke code I got  exception:

```
   WARNING: IOP00810011: Exception from readValue on ValueHandler in CDRInputStream
org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: WARNING: IOP00810011: Exception from readValue on ValueHandler in CDRInputStream  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 11 completed: Maybe
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:248)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:95)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.handleFullLogging(WrapperGenerator.java:387)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.access$400(WrapperGenerator.java:107)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator$2.invoke(WrapperGenerator.java:511)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.proxy.CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.java:99)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.valuehandlerReadException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readRMIIIOPValueType(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1022)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1123)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputObject.read_value(CDRInputObject.java:531)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectField(IIOPInputStream.java:2162)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputClassFields(IIOPInputStream.java:2404)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1224)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:425)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:308)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readRMIIIOPValueType(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1015)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1123)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:935)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_abstract_interface(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:928)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_abstract_interface(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:918)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputObject.read_abstract_interface(CDRInputObject.java:557)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.readObjectDelegate(IIOPInputStream.java:391)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.readObjectOverride(IIOPInputStream.java:544)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:364)
    at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:771)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.invokeObjectReader(IIOPInputStream.java:1832)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1214)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:425)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:308)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readRMIIIOPValueType(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1015)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1123)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputObject.read_value(CDRInputObject.java:531)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectField(IIOPInputStream.java:2162)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputClassFields(IIOPInputStream.java:2404)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1224)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:425)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:308)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readRMIIIOPValueType(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1015)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1123)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputObject.read_value(CDRInputObject.java:531)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectField(IIOPInputStream.java:2162)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputClassFields(IIOPInputStream.java:2404)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1224)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:425)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:308)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readRMIIIOPValueType(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1015)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1123)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:935)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_abstract_interface(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:928)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_abstract_interface(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:918)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputObject.read_abstract_interface(CDRInputObject.java:557)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.readObjectDelegate(IIOPInputStream.java:391)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.readObjectOverride(IIOPInputStream.java:544)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:364)
    at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:771)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.invokeObjectReader(IIOPInputStream.java:1832)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1214)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:425)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:308)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readRMIIIOPValueType(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1015)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1123)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputObject.read_value(CDRInputObject.java:531)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectField(IIOPInputStream.java:2162)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputClassFields(IIOPInputStream.java:2404)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1224)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:425)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:308)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readRMIIIOPValueType(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1015)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1123)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputObject.read_value(CDRInputObject.java:531)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectField(IIOPInputStream.java:2162)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputClassFields(IIOPInputStream.java:2404)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1224)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:425)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:308)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readRMIIIOPValueType(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1015)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1123)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputObject.read_value(CDRInputObject.java:531)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectField(IIOPInputStream.java:2162)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputClassFields(IIOPInputStream.java:2404)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.defaultReadObjectDelegate(IIOPInputStream.java:596)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.InputStreamHook.defaultReadObject(InputStreamHook.java:233)
    at java.lang.Throwable.readObject(Throwable.java:914)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.invokeObjectReader(IIOPInputStream.java:1832)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1214)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:425)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:308)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readRMIIIOPValueType(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1015)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1123)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputObject.read_value(CDRInputObject.java:531)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectField(IIOPInputStream.java:2162)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputClassFields(IIOPInputStream.java:2404)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.defaultReadObjectDelegate(IIOPInputStream.java:596)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.InputStreamHook.defaultReadObject(InputStreamHook.java:233)
    at java.lang.Throwable.readObject(Throwable.java:914)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.invokeObjectReader(IIOPInputStream.java:1832)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1214)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:425)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:308)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readRMIIIOPValueType(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1015)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1123)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputObject.read_value(CDRInputObject.java:531)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectField(IIOPInputStream.java:2162)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputClassFields(IIOPInputStream.java:2404)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.defaultReadObjectDelegate(IIOPInputStream.java:596)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.InputStreamHook.defaultReadObject(InputStreamHook.java:233)
    at java.lang.Throwable.readObject(Throwable.java:914)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.invokeObjectReader(IIOPInputStream.java:1832)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1214)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:425)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:308)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readRMIIIOPValueType(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1015)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1123)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputObject.read_value(CDRInputObject.java:531)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ExceptionHandlerImpl$ExceptionRWRMIImpl.read(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:180)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ExceptionHandlerImpl.readException(ExceptionHandlerImpl.java:290)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.readException(DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.java:502)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:205)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:152)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.codegen.CodegenStubBase.invoke(CodegenStubBase.java:227)
    at com.tinkoff.ws.wsconnections.beans.__IQuoteSetEJB_Remote_DynamicStub.getConnection(com/tinkoff/ws/wsconnections/beans/__IQuoteSetEJB_Remote_DynamicStub.java)
    at com.tinkoff.ws.wsconnections.beans._IQuoteSetEJB_Wrapper.getConnection(com/tinkoff/ws/wsconnections/beans/_IQuoteSetEJB_Wrapper.java)
    at MainACT.main(MainACT.java:39)
Caused by: java.io.OptionalDataException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.createOptionalDataException(IIOPInputStream.java:245)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.handleOptionalDataMarshalException(IIOPInputStream.java:944)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.readObjectDelegate(IIOPInputStream.java:393)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.readObjectOverride(IIOPInputStream.java:544)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:364)
    at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:771)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.invokeObjectReader(IIOPInputStream.java:1832)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1214)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:425)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:308)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readRMIIIOPValueType(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1015)
    ... 145 more
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: FINE: IOP00800008: Not enough optional data available  vmcid: SUN  minor code: 8  completed: No
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:248)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.corba.CorbaExtension.makeException(CorbaExtension.java:95)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.handleFullLogging(WrapperGenerator.java:387)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator.access$400(WrapperGenerator.java:107)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.logex.WrapperGenerator$2.invoke(WrapperGenerator.java:511)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.proxy.CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(CompositeInvocationHandlerImpl.java:99)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26.rmiiiopOptionalDataIncompatible3(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.checkBlockLength(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:377)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_2.alignAndCheck(CDRInputStream_1_2.java:105)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_long(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:496)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readValueTag(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1810)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:1040)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:935)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_abstract_interface(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:928)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_abstract_interface(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:918)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputObject.read_abstract_interface(CDRInputObject.java:557)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.readObjectDelegate(IIOPInputStream.java:391)
    ... 158 more

javax.ejb.EJBException: java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA MARSHAL 1330446347 Maybe; nested exception is: 
    org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: WARNING: IOP00810011: Exception from readValue on ValueHandler in CDRInputStream  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 11 completed: Maybe
    at com.tinkoff.ws.wsconnections.beans._IQuoteSetEJB_Wrapper.getConnection(com/tinkoff/ws/wsconnections/beans/_IQuoteSetEJB_Wrapper.java)
    at MainACT.main(MainACT.java:39)
javax.ejb.NoSuchEJBException
    at com.tinkoff.ws.wsconnections.beans._IQuoteSetEJB_Wrapper.getConnection(com/tinkoff/ws/wsconnections/beans/_IQuoteSetEJB_Wrapper.java)
    at MainACT.main(MainACT.java:39)
javax.ejb.NoSuchEJBException
    at com.tinkoff.ws.wsconnections.beans._IQuoteSetEJB_Wrapper.getConnection(com/tinkoff/ws/wsconnections/beans/_IQuoteSetEJB_Wrapper.java)
    at MainACT.main(MainACT.java:39)
Caused by: java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException: CORBA OBJECT_NOT_EXIST 9999 No; nested exception is: 
    org.omg.CORBA.OBJECT_NOT_EXIST: ----------BEGIN server-side stack trace----------
org.omg.CORBA.OBJECT_NOT_EXIST:   vmcid: 0x2000  minor code: 1807  completed: No
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.POARemoteReferenceFactory.preinvoke(POARemoteReferenceFactory.java:528)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.oa.poa.POAPolicyMediatorImpl_NR_USM.internalGetServant(POAPolicyMediatorImpl_NR_USM.java:93)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.oa.poa.POAPolicyMediatorBase.getInvocationServant(POAPolicyMediatorBase.java:139)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.oa.poa.POAImpl.getInvocationServant(POAImpl.java:1805)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.getServant(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:286)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.getServantWithPI(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:311)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:196)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1549)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1425)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(MessageMediatorImpl.java:930)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:213)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:694)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(MessageMediatorImpl.java:496)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.doWork(MessageMediatorImpl.java:2222)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)

----------END server-side stack trace----------  vmcid: 0x2000  minor code: 1807  completed: No
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.mapSystemException(Util.java:269)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:213)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:152)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.codegen.CodegenStubBase.invoke(CodegenStubBase.java:227)
    at com.tinkoff.ws.wsconnections.beans.__IQuoteSetEJB_Remote_DynamicStub.getConnection(com/tinkoff/ws/wsconnections/beans/__IQuoteSetEJB_Remote_DynamicStub.java)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.OBJECT_NOT_EXIST: ----------BEGIN server-side stack trace----------
org.omg.CORBA.OBJECT_NOT_EXIST:   vmcid: 0x2000  minor code: 1807  completed: No
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.POARemoteReferenceFactory.preinvoke(POARemoteReferenceFactory.java:528)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.oa.poa.POAPolicyMediatorImpl_NR_USM.internalGetServant(POAPolicyMediatorImpl_NR_USM.java:93)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.oa.poa.POAPolicyMediatorBase.getInvocationServant(POAPolicyMediatorBase.java:139)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.oa.poa.POAImpl.getInvocationServant(POAImpl.java:1805)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.getServant(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:286)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.getServantWithPI(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:311)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(ServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:196)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1549)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:1425)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(MessageMediatorImpl.java:930)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:213)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(MessageMediatorImpl.java:694)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(MessageMediatorImpl.java:496)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.MessageMediatorImpl.doWork(MessageMediatorImpl.java:2222)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)

----------END server-side stack trace----------  vmcid: 0x2000  minor code: 1807  completed: No
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.MessageBase.getSystemException(MessageBase.java:900)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.ReplyMessage_1_2.getSystemException(ReplyMessage_1_2.java:131)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.getSystemExceptionReply(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:637)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.processResponse(CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.java:499)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.marshalingComplete(CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.java:373)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaClientDelegateImpl.invoke(CorbaClientDelegateImpl.java:273)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:200)
    ... 5 more
```

**IMPORTANT** If I make  my `public QuoteSetInterface getConnection()` return `String` in class `QuoteSet_EsbWs` everything works! 
What the problem do I face here? 
I made all my classes even `QuoteSetInterface, QuoteSetInterface_Service` implements Serilizable.
Pelase help